# Error starting Spring Boot microservice with KPL/KCL enabled

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am starting my Spring Boot microservice locally with Localstack running. When I start it with `spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.kpl-kcl-enabled=false`, it starts just fine. Setting this value to `true` causes the following stack trace.:

```
Unable to load credentials from com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@58faba32: Unable to load credentials into profile [default]: AWS Access Key ID is not specified.
c.a.s.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer   : Error in child process
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error running child process
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.fatalError(Daemon.java:533)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.fatalError(Daemon.java:513)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.access$200(Daemon.java:63)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon$1.run(Daemon.java:135)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@71435b85: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint, com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@58faba32: Unable to load credentials into profile [default]: AWS Access Key ID is not specified.]
at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:136)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.makeSetCredentialsMessage(Daemon.java:565)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.startChildProcess(Daemon.java:436)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.access$100(Daemon.java:63)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon$1.run(Daemon.java:133)
```

In the [release announcement for the 2.0.0 version of the Kinesis Cloud Stream Kinesis Binder](https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/27/spring-integration-aws-2-3-ga-and-spring-cloud-stream-kinesis-binder-2-0-ga-available), it states that "the main theme of both these releases is about an integration testing using a Local Stack framework which helped us to spot several bugs and race conditions in both libraries."

I have `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` set as environment variables alongside other environment variables that my Docker stack uses, so I'm confused why I'm receiving this error.

Are there any additional configurations I need to specify so that I can enable KPL/KCL and run and test it locally using LocalStack?

Comment: do u have the 'AWS_CBOR_DISABLE=1' env var set ?

Comment: I do not. What does setting that variable do?

Comment: Setting that didn't make a difference. Same stack trace.

Comment: CBOR is a protocol not supported by kinsalite which is what localstack uses. I think localstack only supports KCL version 1. If you r using KCL version 2 this could also be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

My Local Stack JUnit configuration when KPL involved is like this:

```
@LocalstackDockerProperties(environmentVariableProvider = LocalStackSslEnvironmentProvider.class,
    services = { "kinesis", "dynamodb", "cloudwatch" })
```

Where that `LocalStackSslEnvironmentProvider` has an implementation like this:

```
/**
 * An {@link IEnvironmentVariableProvider} implementation to provide a {@code USE_SSL}
 * environment variable for docker to start a Local Stack in TLS mode.
 * Also this class populates a {@value SDKGlobalConfiguration#DISABLE_CERT_CHECKING_SYSTEM_PROPERTY}
 * system property to disable SSL certificates validation.
 *
 * @author Artem Bilan
 *
 * @since 2.3
 */
public class LocalStackSslEnvironmentProvider implements IEnvironmentVariableProvider {

    static {
        System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.DISABLE_CERT_CHECKING_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getEnvironmentVariables() {
        return Collections.singletonMap("USE_SSL", "true");
    }

}
```

Hope this will help you, too.

Comment: In my case, I'm not running a JUnit test. I'm starting LocalStack as a separate container and my microservice as another container. I saw your post on a GitHub issue: https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/507#issuecomment-545230521. On that thread, it was mentioned that the LocalStack docker-compose needed to have ```AWS_CBOR_DISABLE=true``` and ```USE_SSL=true``` specified. Is that true? Also, it's not clear to me that the solution you propose is related to the problem I'm experiencing. Can you provide clarification as to what may be occurring?

Comment: The KPL works via TLS protocol, not plain HTTP. So, I’ve managed to make it working only with those options for SSL. It’s really doesn’t matter how you run the Localstack, the options are still the same.

Comment: My understanding of using KPL/KCL with Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis is that all we should have to do is set ```spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.kpl-kcl-enabled=true```. I just want to clarify that's the case, because I saw in your post at https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/507#issuecomment-545230521 that you were creating a ```KinesisProducerConfiguration``` bean in addition to the other test code you posted. I'm in the middle of trying to migrate our code base to use KPL/KCL and want to ensure I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: Well, Spring Cloud Stream is really opinionated against some default configuration and environment. In most cases we definitely talk about AWS. If you try to make something against Localstack, you are on your own. See that my comment: you really can borrow some pieces from there. I mean this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/aws/ExtendedDockerTestUtils.java. Especially pay attention to the `ssl` option. The client for KPL must be an HTTPS one.  Also pay attention to that custom `KinesisProducerConfiguration`.

Comment: You can have that custom code in some *profile* which is going to be disabled when you go in production on the real AWS.

Comment: I am getting back to working on this task after a couple weeks of other work. As far as that custom ```KinesisProducerConfiguration``` goes, I noticed that I had to specify the version of the ```<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId><artifactId>amazon-kinesis-producer</artifactId>``` dependency that I added to my ```pom.xml``` file. I expected this library to be a dependency somewhere in the Spring Cloud AWS chain and was surprised to find out it wasn't.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. That dependency is hard one for the `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis` artifact. See its POM: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis/2.0.1.RELEASE/jar

Comment: Also, at this point, I am wondering if it's even worth the effort to enable KPL/KCL when running microservice Docker containers in my local environment that hit LocalStack and instead just enable this when deploying to AWS. Would that eliminate a lot of these issues? My biggest concern is polluting my Spring auto configuration classes with beans that I really only need when testing locally, even if those beans are specified with ```@Profile("local")```. Should migrating my microservices to utilize KPL/KCL be as easy as setting ```spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.kpl-kcl-enabled=true```?

Comment: If you are not going to test them against LocalStack, then it is not. You might need an access to CloudWatch alongside with DynamoDB though.

Comment: We are testing our microservices using LocalStack, but I'm just wondering if we could test with KPL/KCL not enabled, and simply run the same code when deployed to AWS with it only enabled there. That should still work, right?

Comment: I wouldn't do that because regular client has some difference from KPL+KCL. It might be better to have a testing account on AWS if you can't manage to test in in LocalStack. Anyway the LocalStack doesn't have the whole coverage in functionality against a normal AWS service.

Comment: OK. If you don't mind, can you please let me know what the regular client differences are from KPL+KCL? I'm not sure that I have my beans configured correctly based on what you just mentioned. I thought, after reading the Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis Binder documentation, that the only thing I have to do differently from what we're currently doing is set ```spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.kpl-kcl-enabled=true```. When enabling KPL/KCL, what other property and bean configurations are required, and are there specific configurations to avoid because they would conflict with KPL/KCL?

Comment: The point is that sending messages via regular Kinesis client might not be consumed properly via KCL and vise versa in case of KPL. So, it would be great to stick just with regular one or only with KPL+KCL: no mixing. There is no conflicts in beans, but you definitely don't need `CheckpointStore` and `LockRegistry` to configure for KCL, but you need to have a CloudWatch. Also regular client can deal with several streams, plus shards distribution via `count` & `index`, meanwhile KCL can deal only with a single stream.

Comment: So, you're saying that with KCL, a microservice can't have more than one ```@StreamListener```? The whole reason I'm wanting to use KPL/KCL is because I want to run more than one instance of a microservice and have each microservice processing different shards without having to configure the ```count``` and ```index```. In fact, I'm not even sure how to configure the ```count``` and ```index``` since we're not deploying each instance of a microservice individually. We have a service orchestrator that does that work for us. Have you run across a good way to configure this in an automated way?

Comment: No, that's not. I mean that with KCL one binding has to be tied to only one stream. That's KCL limitation. You are free to have as many `@StreamListener` as you need as long as their bindings are pointing to a single stream. Different bindings though can point to the same stream - concurrency. We usuall rely on `count` & `index` in the Cloud Foundry environment. Might not be a case with AWS...

Comment: Well this surprises me. I didn't understand that limitation. So, in effect, this means I can't have the following properties for the same microservice and use KCL: ```spring.cloud.stream.bindings.stream-1.destination=stream-1``` and ```spring.cloud.stream.bindings.stream-2.destination=stream-2```. Currently, I have a single microservice with two ```@StreamListener```s - one that listens for messages on stream-1 and the other that listens for messages on stream-2. Unless I'm misunderstanding your comments, this is actually hard to believe that KCL can't handle this scenario.

Comment: But you have different bindings - `stream-1.destination` & `stream-2.destination`. So, you are good to have that configuration in a single app and have `@StreamListener` for each of them.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying that for me. One more question: I can have other, separate microservices that utilize KCL that also listen to ```stream-1.destination``` and ```stream-2.destination```, right? Before going down this KPL/KCL path any further, I just want to ensure that the pub/sub approach will work as it has up to this point for us.

Comment: Well, you need to understand for yourself a `consumer group` abstraction: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#consumer-groups. As long as your micorservice instances use the same `group`, there are going to compete for the same stream. And hopefully KCL will distribute shards between them. I saw some concerns in the Internet on the matter, but that's already out of Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis Binder control. If they have different groups, you're indeed are going to have a pub-sub semantics.

Comment: I am much further along now getting KPL/KCL enabled locally using LocalStack. I did have to create a ```AmazonCloudWatchAsync``` bean. Did you have to create a bean for ```com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.proxies.KinesisProxy```? I am encountering an exception ```Unable to load credentials from service endpoint, com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@493968a9: Unable to load credentials into profile [default]: AWS Access Key ID is not specified.``` at ```com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.proxies.KinesisProxy.listShards(KinesisProxy.java:313)```.

Comment: I use `TestUtils.getCredentialsProvider()` and in the end it looks like this for me: `new KclMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(
     TEST_STREAM, AMAZON_KINESIS, CLOUD_WATCH, DYNAMO_DB, TestUtils.getCredentialsProvider())`

Comment: I am now experiencing an error at ```at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:240)```. I turned on AWS logging and can see that the describe stream operation is trying to hit ```host:kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com``` even though I have created an ```AmazonKinesisAsync``` instance that is configured to point to LocalStack. It looks like the code at ```org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.provisioning.KinesisStreamProvisioner.createOrUpdate(KinesisStreamProvisioner.java:135)``` doesn't pick up my bean.